# Error in xml tag </RelativeLayout> (</LinearLayout>) </ScrollView> </LinearLayout> bracketted line please solve this answer guys

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />
    <ScrollView android:background="@drawable/profpicback" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/user_update_header" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="194.0dip">
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="135.29999dip" android:layout_height="135.29999dip">
                    <com.mobiroller.core.views.CircleImageView android:id="@id/user_update_profile_image" android:layout_width="133.29999dip" android:layout_height="133.29999dip" app:civ_border_color="@color/white" app:civ_border_width="4.0dip" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp" />
                    <com.mobiroller.core.views.CircleImageView android:id="@id/user_update_open_gallery" android:layout_width="40.0dip" android:layout_height="40.0dip" android:src="@color/black" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" app:civ_border_color="@color/black" app:civ_fill_color="@color/black" />
                    <RelativeLayout>
                        <ImageView android:id="@id/user_update_image_edit" android:padding="6.0dip" android:layout_width="40.0dip" android:layout_height="40.0dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_white_24dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/user_update_form" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@id/user_update_header">
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@id/user_update_list" android:background="#0000ffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="13.299988dip" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        **</LinearLayout>**
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Having error in bold line please anyone tell solving

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get and describe the problem you have.

Answer (score -1):

Every xml tag must have a closing tag.
For exmaple: Every

```
<RelativeLayout ...
```

must have a

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

tag. 
You are opening 4 Relative layout tags but only close 2 of it.
Btw I suggest formatting your xml for better readability.